# Javascript object closure context

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some JS object. Getting stuck on something, I don't understand how contexts work. Here is a simple example :

```
var MyApp = function(el) {
    this.el = el;
};

MyApp.prototype.bind = function() {
    window.setTimeout(this.start, 300);
}

MyApp.prototype.test = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}

MyApp.prototype.start = function() {
    console.log(this); // Returns the window context
    this.test('Hello'); // Doesn't work, of course.
}

var myapp = new MyApp(el);
myapp.bind();
```

Problem is when calling the start method, I'm in the window context because of the window.setTimeout. Is there a way to fix this or is it a pattern design issue?

Thanks ;)

Comment: One of the solutions on that question talks about using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to fix the issue - don't confuse it with your own `bind` function you've defined.

Comment: This was already marked as a duplicate, but @GillesC is correct from what I can tell.  You can apply the correct context with `window.setTimeout(this.start.bind(this), 300);`.

Comment: Well I might have found something:

Comment: Hello, yeah sorry, I was posting my own reply but you were faster.